# Why was the episode called "Born to the Purple"?

Tags: babylon-5, title-explanation

Having recently watched "[Born to the Purple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_to_the_Purple)", season 1 episode 3 of *Babylon 5*, I'm still puzzled about the name. The only mention of purple that I can recall in the episode is Londo's Purple Files which are stolen by Adira. But the phrase "born to the purple" has a specific idiomatic meaning, and I'm struggling to think of how this idea figures in the episode, or of any important figures in it which fit that description. Is there some subtext or symbolism that I'm missing?

**Why is the episode called "Born to the Purple"?**

Comment: Purple is the colour of royalty; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_in_the_purple

Comment: @Valorum Yes, I know what the phrase means. My question is, why is the colour of royalty at all relevant to this B5 episode?

Comment: In the episode, the files that Londo keeps on the other noble houses (their dirty little secrets) are his "purple files". He's literally born to have access to the files but the double-meaning is that he's born to royalty or that the files themselves are what makes his family powerful, a society supposedly built on a code of honour but in reality propped up by blackmail and mutual self-destruction.

Comment: Well, guess my answer is pointless now that most of it's in the comments.

Comment: @Terriblefan - In fairness, 90% of what's in the comments is in the question :-)

Comment: @Valorum "*He's literally born to have access to the files*" - if you're sure about this, I guess that would answer my question. I was under the impression that he'd built up that information himself over many years of political scheming.

Comment: @Terriblefan I don't care which of you posts an answer, as long as I get one :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor They're secret family files. Also, the situation with Londo's family is analogous to a noble family in Europe/English history.

Comment: "***His family** has been collecting dirt on other families for years. Like all the noble houses of the great Centauri Republic. That's how they play the game*"

Comment: I'm gonna need to keep a closer eye on if I'm going to steal any more of these questions as you watch. On the other hand, it's awesome people are still finding the show.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_to_the_Purple) about this episode, "This episode is named after the Greek word porphyrogennetos, referring to special birthright or privileged heritage, royal birth."

In the context of the story, I believe the reference the title makes is not to the "Purple Files," but rather to the contrast between Londo's privileged status and Adira's lack thereof.  As I recall, Londo was prepared to throw aside tradition and potentially lose status to be with Adira.  He might have been born to the purple, but she made him happy.

To quote from the [Babylon 5 Wikia](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Born_to_the_Purple):

> [Londo] then offers her a gift: a brooch dating back to the original
>   days of the Republic that belonged to a **noble matriarch of House
>   Mollari**. Adira tries to refuse it, but Londo insists she take it.
>   **Adira is shocked** when Londo tells her he has made reservations for them at Fresh Air, surprised that he is not ashamed to be seen with
>   her. **Londo explains that while status and appearances mean
>   everything to the Centauri, she means more to him than any of it.**

Comment: I kinda doubt that Wiki quote on the Greeks... purple = royalty has gone through quite a lot of cultures since.  Good answer though.

Comment: Radhil - porphyrogennetos means "born in the purple".  In this case "the purple" really is "The Purple", the Porphyra chamber or pavilion of the Great Palace at Constantinople that was lined with porphyry marble on floor, walls, and ceiling.   Since the position of emperor was nominally elective and often usurpative, many men already had children when they became emperor.  Thus "born in the purple" was a special title for imperial sons and daughters born in the Purple Chamber after their fathers became emperor.

Comment: Interesting factoid - Mexican president/dictator Porfirio Diaz (1830-1915) was literally named Porphyry as if his parents could predict his rise to power.